# No autoloader for JTable etc?

Tags: autoload

How come I have to manually include JTable, JModel, etc? Is this for security reasons or just a missing feature?

**Edit**: Top google blog post about it: http://dongilbert.net/php-autoloading-and-joomla/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a missing feature for sure.
To backup this statement:

- Autoloading would not be so spread allover the world if it would lead
  to security issues.
- Joomla looking ahead for PSR-4 autoloading at 4.x
  branch

And If you want it now - look at this [PR](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/11061). If you'll register this loader function - you'll be able to autoload everything. Check description of PR.

Comment: Thank you. Are you saying this function could be used in Joomla 3.6? But that would be quite brutal, right?

Comment: Yes, actually this function can be used even at 3.0 I believe. Brutal? Well you can say so. But it's more like going ahead a little bit: using in 2017 something that would be used in 2018 by majority. There could be some issues if you'll be to hard on using new approach with old code only, but in a major situations - it would work right. Feel free to  contact me if there would be any issues with this code.

Comment: Also I'd like to here as many as possible opinions on https://github.com/joomplace/JooYii - new life to Joomla development as designed

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I checked your JooYii web site, but I think it should contain more information about what the difference is between it and vanilla Joomla. A code example, use-case, improvement etc could be provided.

Comment: Thanks, for response. Working on it, but not quite there yet )